# How to save record in postgres with custom type using scalikejdbc?

Tags: postgresql, scala, scalikejdbc

In my case i have a enum type in postgres:

```
create type my_type as enum (string value);
```

And some tables, using this as column type:

```
create table A (
...
t my_type,
...
)
```

In postgres i can insert new record in table A like this:

```
insert into A values(..., 'my_type_value', ...);
```

Scalikejdbc generates correct sql:

```
 insert into A (...) values (..., 'my_type_value', ...)
```

But fails with an error:

> ERROR: column "t" is of type my_type but expression is of type
>   character varying   HINT: You will need to rewrite or cast the
>   expression.

I tried to do this:

```
object MyType extends Enumeration {...}
case class A(..., t: MyType, ...)
object A extends SQLSyntaxSupport[A] {
  def apply(rs: WrappedResultSet): A = A(..., rs.getString('t'), ...)
}
```

Also, i tried to add implicit convertions in enum type in scala code:

```
object MyType extends Enumeration {
   implicit def stringToValue...
   implicit def valueToString ...
}
```

But it didn't help too.

Insert code looks like this:

```
 withSQL {
      insertInto(A).namedValues(
        ...
        A.column.t-> e.t, // e - passed entity into insert fun
        ....
      )
    }.update().apply()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, solved it.
I have to add implicit converter:

```
 implicit val valueToParameterBinder: ParameterBinderFactory[MyType] = ParameterBinderFactory {
    value => (stmt, indx) => stmt.setObject(indx, value, Types.OTHER)
  }

object A extends SQLSyntaxSupport[A] {
  def apply(rs: WrappedResultSet): A = A(..., rs.getString('t'), ...) // just call getString as usual
}
```